# Firestore Firebase Database Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to set up access rules for my Firestore Firebase database.
(ala. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

I want 3 rules :

1. No access to all tables, except
2. Table `public_data` has `read` access for everyone, and
3. Table `user_data` has `read, write` for just that authenticated user
   (and I guess anyone should be able to create a new user too .. thats a bonus rule)

The rule format seems straight forward enough from the documentation, however using the Simulator available under *console.firebase.google.com > Database > Cloud Firestore > (my db) > Rules > Simulator* the results are not what I expect.

Answer (score 3):

#### Here is what I ended up using :

(https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/[MY_PROJECT_NAME]/database/firestore/rules)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // 2. Table public_data has read access for everyone
    match /public_data/{document=**} {
      allow read, write; 
    }

    // 3. Table user_data has read, write for just that authenticated user
    match /user_data/{userId} {
      allow read, update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    // (and I guess anyone should be able to create a new user too .. thats a bonus rule)
    match /user_data/{document=**} {
      allow create; 
      // and no one can delete a user
    }
  }

}
```

Note that the "1. No access to all tables" happens automatically.

Note that `A read rule can be broken into get and list, while a write rule can be broken into create, update, and delete` - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

I wasn't able to figure out the Simulator that Firestore > Rules provides, I couldn't figure out what path to put into it.
But it is so easy to make the queries of the data that I ended up just testing it myself.

I'm using Flutter, so [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore), & there are examples in your favourite language in the Firebase docs, eg. [here is a read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

Comment: Would you want to limit your user_data creation to the user?  If so, probably want to add `create` along with `update`.  But then keep in mind that the `user_data/{document=**}` will match everything under `user_data`, and rules are OR'd (the allow `create` says that anybody can create user_data -- are you sure about that?).